# Query select of BLOB data in sqlite too slow in iOS using FMDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, blob, fmdb

i'm using FMDB wrapper for my sqlite database, and in the database i store image downloaded from a url, and stored in BLOB data, but when i make a SELECT query in the database like this:

```
SELECT id,img FROM table1 WHERE name = "Carl"
```

and this is the column in the database:

```
img BLOB
```

but the query is very slow, if i remove the img from the query, it's very faster, after i download the image from a url i resized it to make it smaller and so save memory space in this way:

```
NSData *biggerImg = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_image]];

NSData *img = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self imageWithImage:[UIImage biggerImg] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(90, 134)], 1.0);


- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

anyone knows how i can make the query faster? i need that in the query there is also the image.

thanks

Comment: Would it be an option to store the image separately, and only its path in the database? This might be of interest: http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html.

Comment: thank you very much, if you create an answer i will accept it, i want also know i have to store img in this folder right? this: NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here: http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html, it can improve
the SQLite performance if large BLOBs (such as image data) are stored externally, and only the path to the file is recorded in the database.

If you store the images in the "Documents" directory then they are backed up to iCloud (if
the user has activated that feature). If an iCloud backup is not wanted (e.g. because the images can be reloaded from a server at any time), then "Library/Caches" (use `NSCachesDirectory`) would be a better location.

Comment: yes the images change in the time if there is a new version of it, so you suggest me to put it in the NSCachesDirectory? i have also another question, i have put in the Document folder the sqlite.db i have to put it in the NSCachesDirectory? but how  you mean in backed to iCloud? the user can open the file form the mac book for example?

Comment: @Piero: See http://www.apple.com/de/support/icloud/backup/ and https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/.